# NSScrollView doesn't work xcode 4

Tags: interface-builder, scroll, scrollview, xcode

I made an nsscrollview in the interface builder of xcode 4 and i put buttons inside of it's view. The scrollview is clipping the content of the view instead of scrolling it. How come it won't scroll?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to:

- Make sure the buttons are inside the scroll view's content view.
- Make sure that the content view is large enough that it'll scroll. If it's the same size as the scroll view, or smaller, it won't scroll. A scroll view is meant to display a portion of a larger view; if the whole view is already displayed, there's no reason to do any scrolling.